# moving to diffrent nodes when creating an xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to move to a node i already passed in an xml document. Say i have

```
-node 1
    -node 2
-node 1
-node 3
-node 3
```

i have created these using the xml writer and am curently at node 3 but want to go back to node 2 is there a way (I know in the code i could just type it after node2 is created but im assuming there is a reason i cant)

I tried to close the document and reopen it and using .append but it doesnt work as well i feel like there is a more efficient way to do it

```
        XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.Load("mydoc.xml");
        XmlNode Node = Doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild;
        XmlNode Node2 = 
   Doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild;
        XmlNode Node3 = FaultTreeDoc.CreateElement("Node3");
        FaultTreesNode.InsertAfter(Node3, Node2);
        XmlNode Node4 = Doc.CreateElement(num.ToString());
        Node3.AppendChild(Node4);
        Doc.Save("mydoc.xml");
```

i would excpect node4 to apear as a child of node3 but when i open the document there is nothing there its just blank

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  You've shared some code, so an XML sample that demonstrates the problem would make it more likely we can answer.

Comment: Also, `XmlWriter` is forward-only and cannot be reused or rewound, see [Building an XML file iteratively with XmlWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4580774) and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx): `XmlWriter` *Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, **forward-only** way to generate streams or files that contain XML data.*